# How to convert this code from Objective-C to Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
   [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIBarButtonItem* item, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
        item.customView.alpha = alpha;
    }];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIBarButtonItem* item, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
        item.customView.alpha = alpha;
    }];
```

How to convert this block of code to Swift ? thanks.

Comment: You can use for loops

Comment: Very difficult now to choose which answer to accept, downvoted assuming author didn't try anything to solve the issue :/

Comment: You should try to learn the swift language at least.

Comment: I don't understand, why so many duplicate answers !?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to read Apple's documentation on swift. It's fine to ask questions about certain syntax, however, asking someone else to translate code seems like a very doable task for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, `leftBarButtonItems` is an optional array `[UIBarButtonItem]?`,
therefore it can be enumerated with optional chaining and `forEach()`.
`customView` is also an optional `UIView?`, so assignment to the `alpha`
property is done with optional chaining as well:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems?.forEach { item in
    item.customView?.alpha = alpha
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of cool obj-c to swift websites out there. Use one of them and tidy the result up and you're ready to go!

This is the result from objectivec2swift.com:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({(item: UIBarButtonItem, i: Int, stop: Bool) -> Void in
    item.customView.alpha = alpha
})
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({(item: UIBarButtonItem, i: Int, stop: Bool) -> Void in
    item.customView.alpha = alpha
})
```

But that's not the most swifty code. Let's tidy it up:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems?.forEach {
    $0.customView?.alpha = alpha
}
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.forEach {
    $0.customView?.alpha = alpha
}
```

Look at that! So swifty!

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this (and the code from the previous answers) does not compile.

Comment: Yes, I didn't test the code the first time. @MartinR